# Tag synonyms: which is the master one?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I have a doubt about tag synonyms: when presented with the page of a tag where I can suggest synonyms and vote already suggested ones which is the master one? To be more clear: when I suggest or vote for a synonym am I suggesting that the suggested/voted synonym should be the master or that it should be "absorbed" by the tag whose page I'm currently seeing.

The question may seem silly, and some interference from my native language (Italian) could be in action here, but to me the "synonym" relationship is symmetric, and since in that "suggestion/vote" page there is no clear hint to which would be the master, I cannot clearly understand for what I'm voting.

This has some practical consequences in this case: [double-buffering](/questions/tagged/double-buffering) and [doublebuffered](/questions/tagged/doublebuffered). Although this latter has more tagged questions, I think the former is more correct spelling-wise, so I'd like to suggest the former to be the master. In which tag's page should I post my suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag you're currently on would become the master tag when suggesting a synonym. So if you're viewing the synonyms page for [double-buffering](/questions/tagged/double-buffering), then (if approved) the final relationship would be [double-buffering](/questions/tagged/double-buffering) ← [doublebuffered](/questions/tagged/doublebuffered).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! May I suggest that this hint be placed somewhere in that page? Maybe I'm not the only one having this doubt. A simple "(this will be the master tag)" or similar annotation?